# Ambiguous Reference error after recovering a deleted file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I was trying to move a .aspx page over to a new project by copy/pasting. After I did that, I deleted it from the original solution. When I realized this was a mistake, I tried recovering and adding it back to the original solution. I can open it and view the code/designer, but I am getting an error "ambiguous reference" and "already contains a definition for that" on all the objects in the .aspx page...please help!

Comment: Is one project a web site and the other a web application?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two `.Designer.cs` files nested under the ASPX.
Delete one of them.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. It's just page.aspx, page.aspx.cs, and page.aspx.designer.cs

Comment: Ah, you were correct. Somehow it was under a different name. Thanks!